# Control + Break equivalent for Mac in VBA

Tags: macos, vba

If I want to stop my code from executing on a PC, I know I just need to press ctrl+break. But since my Mac has no "break" key I am not sure what to do?

What is the equivalent in Mac?

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33797

Comment: @Santosh just add ur comment as an answer.. will upvote

Comment: @Santosh not working in Excel 2019

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> on Mac to stop the code.

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>ESC</kbd> keys do not function exactly like on the PC.  They do not break to the debugger on a modal dialog box.  Use <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>ESC</kbd> (Press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> twice) to bring up a dialog that allows you to enter the debugger at the location in code of the dialog box display.  Tested in Excel VBA 2011

Answer (score 2):

cntrl-esc works like cntrl-break on my macbook pro to stop Excel vba running under Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for resurrecting this.  This is the first result on a google search so I figured I should answer.

Working in IDEs within a windows VM environment on Mac (eg: Visual Basic for Applications) the command is actually <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I am working on  a Mac. I use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>  to stop my code.

Comment: this should be posted as a comment not as an answer.

Comment: @cod-e-rection How so? It's directly answering the question.

Comment: Thank you @Paul Roub for making it more user appealing.

Answer (score 0):

None of the options listed works on current versions of EXCEL a the way  <.> did in much earlier versions of EXCEL.
 allows you to force-quit EXCEL, alternatively you can do that using the Activity Monitor or by holding the mouse down on the EXCEL icon in the dock and selecting "Force quit" from the menu. However, force quitting EXCEL just kills the EXCEL processing, it does not allow you to access the debugger. So far, I have not found any method to do that - very annoying.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In RDP I am using ⌃ ⌥ E. Try this.